# Excel - Calculating the Difference Between Two Different Hours & Minutes Figures

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns each with a number of hours and minutes, each column is the difference in time between two numbers. So for example the first number 01:46, this is a difference of 1hr 46 minutes and the next number 16:46 is a difference of 16hr 46 minutes

Columns have the format of hh:mm;[Red]-hh:mm

If I do a simple A1-A2 I get 15:00, so 15hrs difference which works however in one of the lines further down I have 19:37 & 14:18 - I am getting -18.41 whereas I want it to show 5hrs 19 minutes

Can anyone advise how I resolve this?

Copy of Data:
[image: Copy of Data]

Comment: Why would 19:37-14:18 be 5hrs 19 minutes? Can you eleborate?

Comment: Try the following formula: `=MAX(A2:B2)-MIN(A2:B2)`

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, I think you want to see the difference between column 01 and 02. `A1-A2` could be a typo and it is `A1-B1`

If the answer `A1-B1 = 15:00` is correct then the difference between `19:37 & 14:18` is `18.41`, because the second column is referring to the next day. If first column refers to next day then  `A1-B1 = 15:00` is wrong. The right answer for it will be `09:00`.

If that is not the case, And you want to subtract lowest time from highest time. You may use `=MAX(A2:B2)-MIN(A2:B2)` as per the comment of @cybernetic.nomad.

However, based on my research `A1-B1` or `B1-A1` will not work for everything because of midnight span. i.e. similar to night shifts for working hours

By Studying from this Video: https://youtu.be/pET80HwhVmE and from your Question + Comments. This is the final Comparision Table. Check below explanations and Choose what you want.

[image]

---

- **Based on Your Question**
- Column C is: `=A1-B1` and Column D is: `=B1-A1`
- C don't work when `B1` is greater than `A1`
- C don't work when `B1` is lower than `A1`

---

- **Based on the YouTube Video**

> 

- If Column B is the next day then Column E Formula: `=IF(A1>B1,B1+1,B1)-A1`
- This is extended version of `B1-A1` with a Condition explained below.
- If Column A is greater than B, then Column B is next day, If not true then it is Today

> 

- If column A is the next day then Column F Formula: `=IF(B1>A1,A1+1,A1)-B1`
- This is extended version of `A1-B1` with a Condition explained below.
- If Column B is greater than A, then Column A is next day, If not true then it is Today

---

- **Based on Comments**
- Column G: `=MAX(A1:B1)-MIN(A1:B1)`
- If you want to subtract lowest time from highest time, regardless of which column.
- This means both time belongs to the *same day* but *not mentioned in proper order* like first column is `from time` and second column is `to time` OR vice versa

---

> I hope you will find a suitable answer to match your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry I didn't explain myself completely. The answers I am after are the ones in column G. I have followed the equation but I am getting the following 15:00
02:15
08:40
06:42
06:39
01:31
09:25
06:16
16:10
19:04
09:39
23:41
06:05
04:10
17:08
09:09
02:53
07:03
23:52
03:52
01:51
11:43
18:41
17:36. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure. I tried it on Microsoft Excel and it did work. Are you using a different software.

Comment: I have opened a new worksheet and have entered the numbers manual and it does calculate correctly. Could it be something to do with the formulas/formats that are in place in how these numbers are calculated in the first place?

Comment: possible, may be some existing formulas are conflicting. someone with deep understanding in this will be able to find it out. Anyway I don't think you will be able to find a solution for such conflicts on a forum, because it will require a full check on your worksheet by a person who knows it well.  If possible try re-entering data manually or try adjusting or eliminating some formulas.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you have written, try: `=ABS(A1-B1)`